# What is $\Omega$ function in probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory

On [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_without_the_dependency_on_the_dimensions) Wikipedia page, there is a $\Omega$ function used:

$$
t = \Omega \left( \frac{\gamma\log (\gamma/\varepsilon^2)}{\varepsilon^2} \right)
$$

Couldn't find what $\Omega$ function stands for here. It doesn't seems to be a [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $\Omega$ (because it's a set not a function).

(Second question: what `poly` function from the same page could stand for?)

Comment: it's landau notation. poly means polynomial

Comment: @AndrewZhang, thanks a lot, makes perfect sense